# np.where gives error message but correct result

Tags: python, numpy

The following code returns an error message I don't understand, although the output is correct.

```
a = np.array([1, 4, 9])

bool_1 = a > 5 
bool_2 = a < 5

a = np.where(bool_1, -np.sqrt(a), a)
array([ 1.,  4., -3.])

a = np.where(bool_2, np.sqrt(a), a)
array([ 1.,  2., -3.])
```

But with error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
a = np.where(bool_2, np.sqrt(a), a)
```

Boolean masks are declared beforehand not to be impacted by the first `np.where`. Why do I get this error message?

Comment: It's not an error but a warning. As described in your other question use `np.sqrt(a, where=bool_1, out=a.astype(float))`.

Comment: It seems that it tries to apply the sqrt over each element (including the -3 present at the second step) no matter what the where is. I would have assumed it only applies it on elements at the index for which the bool_2 condition is True.

As for your second suggestion, i tried it and it works fine. Thanks a lot! Cheers

Comment: Indeed, `np.where` would act after `np.sqrt` already happened ;)

Comment: This is python.  `np.where` is a function.  Its arguments are evaluated in full, and the results are passed in. It is not a conditional processor.

Comment: Ok, I get it! Thanks for your answers guys.