# Strange behaviour of numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy, runtime-error

Consider the code

`np.where(1<=0, np.sqrt(-1), 0)`

When running this, I get

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
array(0.)
```

Why is python even running (somewhere) the first branch? The above code might look stupid but I investigated after I  received the error for what I have in my program:

`np.where(x<= 1, np.sqrt(1-x**2), 1)`

The x array contains positive elements (at least if my other code is right). It wasn't obvious if I had a mistake in my x array because usually I use torch.where, and the same warning is not thrown.

Comment: what do you mean by "the first branch?" I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Just a few days ago someone else tried to use `np.where` with a `sqrt`. 
 Here's the two links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76719175/np-sqrt-with-integers-and-where-condition-returns-wrong-results, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76720127/np-where-gives-error-message-but-correct-result

Comment: @hpaulj. I'm pretty sure I have a much much older duplicate than that somewhere :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no branches (i.e. `if` statements or conditional expressions) in your code. Arguments are fully evaluated when passed as a part of a function call. Perhaps, seeing an equivalent piece of code will make this more clear:

```
_temp0 = 1 <= 0
_temp1 = np.sqrt(-1)
_temp2 = 0
np.where(_temp0, _temp1, _temp2)
```

Python has a [strict and very straightforward evaluation strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). It sounds like you were expecting a [non-strict evaluation strategy like call by name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Non-strict_binding_strategies).

Comment: Thanks. However the same expression runs without warning when I used torch.where, which confused me

Comment: torch.where appears to work the same way, taking arrays/tensors, not functions.  It is possible the sqrt warnings have been silenced.

Comment: @hpaulj it would have to be by `torch` or one of its dependencies I guess.